# How to efficiently operate on sub-arrays like calculating the determinants, inverse,

Tags: python, function, numpy, sub-array

I have to to multiple operations on sub-arrays like matrix inversions or building determinants. Since for-loops are not very fast in Python I wonder what is the best way to do this.

```py
import numpy as np
n = 8
a = np.random.rand(3,3,n)
b = np.empty(n)
c = np.zeros_like(a)

for i in range(n):
    b[i] = np.linalg.det(a[:,:,i])
    c[:,:,i] = np.linalg.inv(a[:,:,i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those [`numpy.linalg`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.linalg.html) functions would accept `n-dim` arrays as long as the last two axes are the ones that form the `2D` slices along which functions are intended to be operated upon. Hence, to solve our cases, permute axes to bring-up the axis of iteration as the first one, perform the required operation and if needed push-back that axis back to it's original place.

Hence, we could get those outputs, like so -

```
b = np.linalg.det(np.moveaxis(a,2,0))
c = np.moveaxis(np.linalg.inv(np.moveaxis(a,2,0)),0,2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution is about 100 times faster than mine =)